# Samsung Tizen Smart TV command Smart Development Bridge < $sdb shell > command returns status is 'closed'. how to enable it.?

Tags: ui-automation, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio, automation-testing

My Real Samsung Smart Tizen series 4 TV is running, my build is ready, I am trying to run the following command to run in debug:

***$ sdb -s 192.168.0.101:26101 shell 0 execute org.tizen.volume-setting***

It returns this :

**closed**

When I run

***$ sdb capability***

I have the following output :

imac@iMacs-iMac-2 ~ % sdb capability
secure_protocol:enabled
intershell_support:disabled
filesync_support:pushpull
usbproto_support:disabled
sockproto_support:enabled
syncwinsz_support:enabled
sdbd_rootperm:disabled
rootonoff_support:disabled
encryption_support:disabled
zone_support:disabled
multiuser_support:enabled
cpu_arch:armv7
sdk_toolpath:/home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools
profile_name:tv
vendor_name:Samsung
can_launch:tv-samsung
device_name:Tizen
platform_version:5.5
product_version:4.0
sdbd_version:2.2.31
sdbd_plugin_version:3.8.0_TV_REL
sdbd_cap_version:1.0
log_enable:disabled
log_path:/tmp
appcmd_support:disabled
appid2pid_support:enabled
pkgcmd_debugmode:enabled
netcoredbg_support:enabled